# How to execute automatically allure report using cucumber js and webdriver io?

Tags: webdriver-io, allure, cucumberjs

I'm using Cucumber Js and Webdriverio. I trying generate report automatically, without execute the command allure says (allure generate "outPut dir" && allure open).

I thinked maybe, executing the command in the hooks of webdriver io file (wdio.conf.js) but i can`t do.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that would be using NPM.

In your `package.json` you can add `script` called `allure` and the value of it as `allure generate "outPut dir" && allure open`

This is how we have it:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "wdio",
"allure-reports": "node_modules/.bin/allure generate ./reports/allure/allure-results/  -o ./reports/allure/allure-report/ --clean && allure open ./reports/allure/allure-report"
```

}

Now while triggering the test, you can use the command `npm run test && npm run allure-reports`

This way, npm would first run the `wdio` test and once that is completed it would trigger the allure script.

Please try that and let us know whether

Comment: what is the npm package are you using? i did not find `allure`, but have `allure-cucumberjs`

Comment: Hi.. The answer above is bit old.. begining days of WDIO.. now the things are improved and changed. Please follow https://webdriver.io/docs/allure-reporter